# Check if playing then change icon on a button

Tags: ios, swift

I am currently using the following to change the button icon, when user has press a playVideo.

However, I need something that will check if the media is currently playing and update this with the correct icon?

I am wondering what is the best way to do this.

```
@IBAction func playVideo(_ sender: Any) {
         if(defaultsKeys.musicplayer_connected == "1"){
            self.defaults.set("0", forKey: defaultsKeys.musicplayer_connected)

        //  (sender as! UIButton).setTitle("Pause", for: [])
            (sender as! UIButton).setBackgroundImage(UIImage(systemName: "pause.circle"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
              MusicPlayer.shared.startBackgroundMusic()

          }else
          {
            self.defaults.set("1", forKey: defaultsKeys.musicplayer_connected)
       //   (sender as! UIButton).setTitle("Play", for: [])

            (sender as! UIButton).setBackgroundImage(UIImage(systemName: "play.circle"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
            MusicPlayer.shared.stopBackgroundMusic()
            //self.player.pause()
          }

      }
```

Comment: @SureshMopidevi because the player is hidden.

Comment: you can use `.normal` , `.selected` , `.highlighted` states of a button

Answer (score 1):

create a enum to store the state of the player

```
enum PlayerState {
    case playing,paused
}
```

then create a property observer that will update your button on the change of the value

```
   var playerStateChanged : PlayerState = .playing {
      didSet {
        switch playerStateChanged {
        case .playing:
            if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
                yourBtn.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(systemName: "play.circle"), for: .normal)
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }
        case .paused:
            if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
                yourBtn.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(systemName: "pause.circle"), for: .normal)
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }
        }
      }
    }
```

Now in your IBAction, update the value of playerStateChanged and it will set the button image accordingly.

```
@IBAction func playVideo(_ sender: Any) {
   // get if player is playing or not and set the value of playerStateChanged
   playerStateChanged = .paused
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Bool` variable and configure the player's `image` and start/stop actions based on its current state.

Create a *computed property* **`isPlaying`**,

```
var isPlaying = false {
    didSet {
        self.playButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: self.isPlaying ? "play.circle" : "pause.circle"), for: <#T##UIControl.State#>)
        self.isPlaying ? MusicPlayer.shared.startBackgroundMusic() : MusicPlayer.shared.stopBackgroundMusic()
    }
}
```

Now, in your `playVideo(_:)` action method, you need to simply change the state of `isPlaying` like so,

```
@IBAction func playVideo(_ sender: Any) {
    self.isPlaying = !self.isPlaying
}
```